# A library for making matplotlib svg output interactive?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am looking for a library that can add basic interactivity to matplotlib figures exported to SVG: toggling layers, showing tooltips on hover, etc.

I do know about [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/user_interfaces/svg_histogram_sgskip.html).   However, before rolling my own solution, I'd like to make sure that I am not reinventing the wheel.
I find it hard to believe that over the years nobody has created a library for this.   And yet... my searches are coming up empty.

Edit: I am looking for something that works with matplotlib, as I already have a bunch of visualizations coded in matplotlib.  Another requirement is that I need exported figures to be locally-viewable (i.e. from a local hard drive), so anything that needs to load external scripts like [mpld3](https://mpld3.github.io/) is out, I believe.

Comment: I think you want an altair chart, but you might need to display that on something like a webpage, that can handle the interactivity piece. I'd recommend [streamlit](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/api.html#display-charts) for that

Comment: I'm in a similar position, albeit a subset of the functionality. @user1411900, did you end up finding a solution? If so, what might it be?

Comment: @lynn No, I did not.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know! I'll set an answer if I end up finding (or making) a tool for this.